# Replacing None values in list of list with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I would like to replace all the None values in a list of list with list comprehension. My code seems to just return to original list of list.

```
Names = [['Jon',None,'Bill'],['Andrew','Robert',None]]
Removed_None = [0 if x is None else x for x in Names]
print Removed_None
```

Desired Output:

```
[['Jon',0,'Bill'],['Andrew','Robert',0]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to *nest* your list comprehensions:

```
[[v if v is not None else 0 for v in nested] for nested in Names]
```

Demo:

```
>>> Names = [['Jon',None,'Bill'],['Andrew','Robert',None]]
>>> [[v if v is not None else 0 for v in nested] for nested in Names]
[['Jon', 0, 'Bill'], ['Andrew', 'Robert', 0]]
```

Comment: Isn't `if v is not None` ... redundant?

Comment: @BhargavRao: not if you want to preserve `''` and other false values that are not `None`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Removed_None = [[0 if item is None else item for item in each_list] for each_list in Names]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested comprehensions (I wrote one as a function for clarity)

```
[['Jon', None, 'Bill'], ['Andrew', 'Robert', None]]
>>> def replace(names):
...     return [0 if name is None else name for name in names]
... 
>>> print [replace(names) for names in Names]
[['Jon', 0, 'Bill'], ['Andrew', 'Robert', 0]]
```